# Removing dependency on nuget package by using an interface?

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget

I am building a new NuGet package to be used by multiple applications. The package does a bunch of stuff and a little bit of JSON work, so initially I used the newtonsoft.json package for this. However I have found that many applications inside the company that I work for use different versions of newtonsoft.json or they use a different library altogether for JSON work.

To remove this dependency on newtonsoft.json, I have created an interface that needs to be implemented by the user. It has one class that looks like this:

```
public interface IJsonConverter
{
    // this function needs to convert the object to a JSON string
    string SerializeObject(object data);

    // this function returns an object for the supplied JSON string
    T DeserializeObject<T>(string value);
}
```

Which can be implemented very easily by each application, say for example:

```
public class JsonConverter:IJsonConverter
{
    public string SerializeObject(object data)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    }
    public T DeserializeObject<T>(string value)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

This means that each application that uses my nuget package does not have to worry about this dependency, and won't have to mess around with binding redirects or get stuck in DLL hell.

Will this approach lead to more problems? Is it an anti-pattern? Are there any better approaches?

Comment: Will your nuget package have a dependency of Newtonsoft?

Comment: Your life will be hard without Json serialization attributes so...

Comment: Indeed this is an option and you may be able to remove dependency on Newtonsoft.JSON library... It's not possible to see if this approach good (solve your problems)… If you have particular concerns about this approach it would make question more scoped/answerable for SO.

Comment: If there are different json serializers per app then using an interface is the right approach. That's what interfaces are for.

Comment: If *your* nuget package is doing some JSON work, how are you doing it? Or is your JSON work abstract and the client needs to implement it? Or are you just exposing an interface in your package?

Comment: @JohanP that's exactly what OP said in his post. That's the approach he has decided to use and he is wondering if it's a good one.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado Well, op said his package has some JSON work to do. Exposing an interface in a nuget package to let the client do the JSON work seems like a useless package to me.

Comment: That's true. I often see this kind of package for internal use in a company. More like a base package for all their projects. If the client can be anyone then indeed it seems useless.

Comment: Yes, the package does more than just the JSON work. That's just a small part of it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks. My particular concern is that I don't know if I'm causing more problems than I'm solving, so I'm not quite sure what to ask. Maybe if this is an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rocklan, you are creating an abstraction. Abstractions are generally better to code to than implementations. If this means someone has to worry about the implementation so be it, but I presume the abstraction has a benefit to you upstream, meaning you can refer to your abstraction everywhere else.

The concrete implementation however will really matter as I think casing for example has flip-flopped.

Practically most everyone is using Newtonsoft.Json, but versions are sooooo all over the place and don't get me started on Azure Functions and that lib :)